Machine (Software) to obtain access token on behalf of user in OAuth 2
I'm kind of new to the all OAuth 2.0 protocol but I think I get the main points in it.
Is it possible to machine to obtain an access token from the authorization server on behalf of a user, that is kind of  machine-to-machine communication with user context?
I use Keycloak as authorization server and a java program need to acquire token for it on behalf of the user but not user or resource owner interaction
